# Android - Play Random Sounds on Button Click

Tags: android, button, audio, random, onclick

i am very new in "coding" for Googles Android.

At the moment i am programming a small app with one button. If you click on it, it plays a random sound. BUT :D ... it plays a sound, on every start an other. But no random sounds if you press the button often.

I dont know where is my mistake.

**Here is the code (don't laugh!):**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //MediaPlayer
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageButton soundbutton;

    //Sounds
    int[] sounds={R.raw.s1, R.raw.s2, R.raw.s3, R.raw.s4, R.raw.s5, R.raw.s6, R.raw.s7, R.raw.s8, R.raw.s9, R.raw.s10};
    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 0;
    int High = 10;
    int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //MediaPlayer
        soundbutton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.randomsoundbutton89);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
        soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
                    }
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Help! (from Germany)!

Comment: Move the `rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low` assignment to inside the `onClick()` method. Otherwise, it's just using the same number repeatedly.

Comment: It works, damn fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get different sound

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//MediaPlayer 
soundbutton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.randomsoundbutton89);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try { 
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
            } 
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
});
```

}